# Iterate over dictionary using list of list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

Hello I have list of list sample and dictionary

```
sample=[[0,0,1440,1440],[3,23040,1440,24480]]

machine_to_intervals[0].append(model.NewIntervalVar(0,0 ,0 , 'week'))
```

desired output is

```
machine_to_intervals[0].append(model.NewIntervalVar(0,1440 ,1440 , 'week'))
machine_to_intervals[3].append(model.NewIntervalVar(23040,1440 ,24880 , 'week'))
```

I have tried below approach

```
sample=[[0,0,1440,1440],[3,23040,1440,24480]]
machine_to_intervals={}

for list in sample:
    machine_to_intervals[sample[0]].append(model.NewIntervalVar(sample[1], sample[2], sample[3],'week'))
```

but getting below error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7588d30dcdef> in <module>
      3 
      4 for list in sample:
----> 5     machine_to_intervals[sample[0]].append(model.NewIntervalVar(sample[1], sample[2], sample[3], 'week'))
      6 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sample` list is 2-dimensional, so you need to iterate/index over both dimensions. You seem to start on the right track in what you have tried, but you should index `list` (from `for list in sample` statement).

Replace `sample` references in for loop with `list` and it should work.

*Also, just for your information, it's not a good practice to have variables named as python object types (e.g. `list`). It would be better to rename it to something different, like:*

```
for data in sample:
    machine_to_intervals[data[0]].append(model.NewIntervalVar(data[1], data[2], data[3],'week'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sample` is a list of lists, and you want to create a dictionary `machine_to_intervals` where entries are given by the inner lists of `sample`, key being the first element, and value being constructed from other 3 elements. So you could do something like this:

```
machine_to_intervals = { x[0]: model.NewIntervalVar(x[1], x[2], x[3], 'week') for x in sample }
```